# java 8 streams filter by list over list

Tags: java-8

I need to filter condition by firstname and lastname in the List of names present in either official or unOfficial names List and return List of EmployeeDetails.
Below are the pojo classes

```
public class EmployeeDetails {
    private NameDetails nameDetails;

    public NameDetails getNameDetails() {
        return nameDetails;
    }
    public void setNameDetails(NameDetails nameDetails) {
        this.nameDetails = nameDetails;
    }
}

public class NameDetails {
    private List<Name> officalName;
    private List<Name> unOfficialName;
    public List<Name> getOfficalName() {
        return officalName;
    }
    public void setOfficalName(List<Name> offiicalName) {
        this.officalName = offiicalName;
    }
    public List<Name> getUnOfficialName() {
        return unOfficialName;
    }
    public void setUnOfficialName(List<Name> unOfficialName) {
        this.unOfficialName = unOfficialName;
    }
}

public class Name {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

I tried for filtering with list of officialNames and it is working fine,but I also want to filter names present in unOfficial Names also.(OR Condition)

```
return employeeDetailList.stream().filter(employeeDetails->(employeeDetails.getNameDetails().getOffiicalName()).stream()
            .anyMatch(name-> (null!=name) && (firstName).equals(name.getFirstName()) && (lastName).equals(name.getLastName())))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Help me to solve the issue.Thanks

Comment: While not very efficient, one possible solution is to simply add both the list to a third one  (combine the two lists) and iterate over that....

Comment: `Stream.concat()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't override `equals/hashCode` (if you could there would be a faster way), then:

```
  employeeDetailList             
         .stream()
         .filter(x -> Stream.concat(
                          x.getNameDetails().getOfficalName().stream(),
                          x.getNameDetails().getUnOfficialName().stream()
                      )
                     .anyMatch(y -> Objects.equals(y.getFirstName(), firstName) &&
                                    Objects.equals(y.getLastName(), lastName)))
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: @Prakash well, its not the most optimal solution.. but it will work, yes

Answer (score 0):

Just add the OR condition:

```
return employeeDetailList.stream().filter(employeeDetails->
            ((employeeDetails.getNameDetails().getOffiicalName()).stream().anyMatch(name-> (null!=name) && (firstName).equals(name.getFirstName()) && (lastName).equals(name.getLastName()))))
            || ((employeeDetails.getNameDetails().getUnOfficialName()).stream().anyMatch(name-> (null!=name) && (firstName).equals(name.getFirstName()) && (lastName).equals(name.getLastName()))))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```